# Adding Item ID to OmniPay PayPal request

Tags: paypal, omnipay

The **PayPal csv report** has a column called `Item ID`.

Other checkout implementations fill this column with a comma separated list of item IDs. How do I go about achieving this with the [OmniPay PayPal](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay-paypal) library?

I'm already supplying the array of items using `setItems`, but this doesn't seem to have any bearing on that column.

For example: "90,91,84,83".

Comment: Which of the Omnipay PayPal gateways are you using? Express, Pro or REST?  I would recommend REST as the interface is newer and better documented.

Comment: I used Express.